# Hard Drive playing up

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Hard Drive playing up - it opens quickly but when I select a file, instead of opening immediately, Explorer seems to scan the whole drive and then hangs (Not responding); when it stops "Not responding" new attempts to interact get the same result. This only started recently.

Comment: Do you have a virus checker installed?  What happens if you disable it?

Answer (score 1):

When I was having issues with my 7200RPM Seagate, i got a BOOT CD called Spin Rite. You can boot your PC from it and do some scans on your HD. It might find some bad clusters, sections of the disk. Thats what happened to me. The disk would work fine until the PC tried writing data in the broken sections, It would hang, and I had to restart the PC.

You can try doing a surface scan as well, defragment your drive...

Good luck.

Comment: Quick response, thanks Mate. Tried surface scan (Glary Utilities CheckDisk reports NO problems) & defrag regularly. Will get Spin Rite & take it for a spin.